# Align tabularx in list: missing [t] option

Tags: vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate, tabularx

With a `tabular`, the optional argument `[t]` can set the alignment to top, which is handy when putting a table inside a list item. This aligns the first line of the table with the list number.

Is there any way to do this with `tabularx`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{cheeselist}
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\newenvironment{cheese}
  {\item \tabularx{\linewidth}{l X}}
  {\endtabularx}

\newcommand{\cheesename}[1]{Name & #1\\}
\newcommand{\cheesecolor}[1]{Color & #1\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{cheeselist}

\begin{cheese}
\cheesename{Cheddar}
\cheesecolor{Yellow or White}
\end{cheese}

\begin{cheese}
\cheesename{Swiss (Emmentaler)}
\cheesecolor{White}
\end{cheese}

\end{cheeselist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I now realize it is also possible to do this with the `tabu` package: `\begin{tabu} to \linewidth [t]{l R}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the syntax is

```
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}[<pos>]{<col spec>}
% tabular content
\end{tabularx}
```

Here is you example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{cheeselist}
  {\begin{enumerate}}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\newenvironment{cheese}
  {\item \tabularx{\linewidth}[t]{l X}}
  {\endtabularx}

\newcommand{\cheesename}[1]{Name & #1\\}
\newcommand{\cheesecolor}[1]{Color & #1\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{cheeselist}

\begin{cheese}
\cheesename{Cheddar}
\cheesecolor{Yellow or White}
\end{cheese}

\begin{cheese}
\cheesename{Swiss (Emmentaler)}
\cheesecolor{White}
\end{cheese}

\end{cheeselist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is this documented?

Comment: @AndrewCashner: An undocumented *feature*. It only mentions (roughly) that "`tabularx` takes the same arguments as `tabular*`".

Comment: @AndrewCashner it is now: https://latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/trunk/required/tools/